# InverseFunction of [E, 1, 1][c/Sqrt[K[1]]] isn't it just Log[c/Sqrt[K[1]]?

Tags: inverse

The problem is

```
DSolve[E[del x'[t]/x[t]] x[t]^.5 == c, x[t], t]
```

the answer is

```
{{x[t] -> InverseFunction[         
     Integrate[1/(K[1]*InverseFunction[E, 1, 1][c/Sqrt[K[1]]]), 
               {K[1], 1, #1}] & ][t/del + C[1]]}}
```

The question is: Why doesn't the `InverseFunction[E, 1, 1][c/Sqrt[K[1]]]` appear just as `Log[c/Sqrt[K[1]]`.

Isn't   `InverseFunction[E, 1, 1][c/Sqrt[K[1]]]==Log[c/Sqrt[K[1]]`??

Thanks in advance,  Phil  (relative newbie to Mathematica).

Answer (score 4):

E is not a function. It is a number.

You want Exp. Not E. Or you want to write E^(x) instead of E[x].

Begin by fixing this.

```
InverseFunction[Exp][x]

Log[x]
```

1. One of the first steps to debugging an issue like this is to ask: "Does this function I defined seem to work?". You can test the function for some simple inputs and see that it doesn't work:

   (* Nothing Happens *) E[1.]
2. Another first step in debugging is to reduce the problem down as much as possible. You would find that you are asking: "why doesn't this example work?".

   InverseFunction[E][x]

As a side note, the most common reason that people report that Inverse doesn't work is that Mathematica works with Complex numbers by default. Very often they are only considering the function's behavior over Real values.

Comment: If you run the DSolve above one gets the expression "InverseFunction[E, 1, 1][c/Sqrt[K[1]]]"  Yes I know that "e" is a number but mathematica is using it as a function which I do not understand.Try it.  I guess you are telling me that the reason that the inverse of some exponential expression is not a log is that the solution can be complex, right?

Comment: You used E as a function. Mathematica just went with it.
Go back to your DSolve expression and use Exp instead of E.
Mathematica used E as a function only because you asked it to.

Comment: @PhillipLederer Just replace `E` with `Exp` as Searke says and you'll see `DSolve` works as expected. Using `E` as a function is just a user error. End of discussion.